# toggle class when two elements have swapped places?

Tags: jquery

Im using jquery to move divs either up or down, which is part of a ranking system, so I need the ranking classes to stay the same depending on whether the div is either first, second, third and so on...
The top div should always have class first, second div class equals second etc etc...
Any help much appr.

html:

```
<div class="top5 first">
    <div class="voter">
        <a class="up" href="#">up</a>
        <a class="down" href="#">down</a>
    </div>                    
</div>


<div class="top5 second">
    <div class="voter">
        <a class="up" href="#">up</a>
        <a class="down" href="#">down</a>
    </div>                    
</div>

<div class="top5 third">
    <div class="voter">
        <a class="up" href="#">up</a>
        <a class="down" href="#">down</a>
    </div>                    
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $('.up').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        parent.insertBefore(parent.prev());

    });
    $('.down').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        parent.insertAfter(parent.next());

    });
```

Comment: Perhaps try `var n = 1; $("div").each(...; n+=1;)`?

Comment: the wrapping element has a class of "contentContainer"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is asimpler pure css method!
yoops, you can do this:

```
some-parent div:nth-child(0){
    do css
}  
some-parent div:nth-child(1){
    do another css
}  
some-parent div:nth-child(2){
    do another css
}
```

i think this is very much simpler than adding some extra calculation to your page

Comment: This isn't quite what he is asking for

Comment: there is no need to manipulate the dom directly, i try to show the best way not what he want. and i think thats the perpose of this site!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI you can do it by using `switchClass` (but implementing your own "switch" isn't so difficult):

http://jsfiddle.net/vvBuF/2/

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
function switchClasses(elem1, elem2) {
    if(!elem1 || elem1.length === 0 || 
       !elem2 || elem2.length === 0) { return; }
    var from = '';
    var to = '';
    $.each(classes, function(i, e){if(elem1.hasClass(e)) {from=e;}});
    $.each(classes, function(i, e){if(elem2.hasClass(e)) {to=e;}});
    switchClass(elem1, from, to);
    switchClass(elem2, to, from);
}

function switchClass(elem, from, to) {
    elem.removeClass(from);
    elem.addClass(to);
}

$('.up').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var prev = parent.prev();
    parent.insertBefore(prev);
    switchClasses(parent, prev);
});
$('.down').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var next = parent.next();
    parent.insertAfter(next);
    switchClasses(parent, next);
});
```

or you can just `recalculate` from bottom up:

http://jsfiddle.net/7fkbf/

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
function recalculate() {
    $('.top5').each(function(index) {
        var t = $(this);
        $.each(classes, function(i,e) {t.removeClass(e);});
        t.addClass(classes[index]);
    });
}


$('.up').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var prev = parent.prev();
    parent.insertBefore(prev);
    recalculate();
});
$('.down').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var next = parent.next();
    parent.insertAfter(next);
    recalculate();
});
```